# Has a streaming service original program ever reached 100 episodes?

Tags: distribution, film-industry

American TV series often want to reach 100 episodes so they can be sold into syndication. Streaming services, however, seem less motivated to reach this goal; Netflix series typically have 8-10 episodes per season and they are notorious for [cancelling shows after 3 seasons](https://screenrant.com/netflix-cancels-shows-three-seasons-why/). Inspired by *Lucifer* ending its run at 93 episodes (83 + [10 in season 6](https://tvline.com/2020/09/08/lucifer-final-season-6-episode-count/#!)), just short of the goal, I was curious to know if a streaming service had ever renewed a series enough to put it into syndication. It's OK if the series started on another network as long as it had less than 100 episodes before the service renewed it.

The full 100 isn't always necessary; Netflix [has sold Bojack Horseman reruns to Comedy Central](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/netflix-cuts-its-first-original-series-syndication-deal-to-cable-tv-could-more-follow) despite it finishing at 77 episodes.

Comment: FYI it is no longer 100 episodes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_episodes . Also, in an era of streaming services syndication isn't that relevant anymore.

Comment: If only there was some sort of service where you could watch all of those streaming service original programs after their original air date, even though they are not syndicated. Oh, wait …

Comment: @JörgWMittag My point was that streaming services could potentially sell their shows to other networks.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

On Netflix, the series *[Chelsea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelsea_(TV_series))* reached 120 episodes, while *[Trailer Park Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailer_Park_Boys)* (a continuation) had 55 episodes before Netflix picked it up and was renewed until it had 105.

On Amazon, the series *[Selfie with Bajrangi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfie_With_Bajrangi)* was commissioned for 104 episodes over 2 seasons and went into syndication on the Disney channel. In 2020 Disney+Hotstar renewed it for 234 more episodes. However, its episodes are only 11 minutes long.

The nearest qualifying series on Disney+ is *[One Day at Disney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Day_at_Disney_(TV_series))*, at 51 episodes.

This answer is community wiki, so anyone is welcome to update it as new programming is released.